# Product price won't update on product page front end. Cache stuck

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, varnish, product-page, product-prices

I have a product that has a sale price of 199.99 and an original price of 240.

In my index table I can see that the price has been indexed: (`catalog_product_index_price`):

```
'123', 'cust_grp', 'website_id', 'tax_class', '240.000000', '199.990000', '199.990000', '199.990000', NULL
'123', 'cust_grp', 'website_id', 'tax_class', '240.000000', '199.990000', '199.990000', '199.990000', NULL
'123', 'cust_grp', 'website_id', 'tax_class', '240.000000', '199.990000', '199.990000', '199.990000', NULL
.......
.......
```

This goes on for all stores, customer groups and tax combos. The indexed data is correct.

The product page shows the 240.00 price and when you add the product to the cart it shows a price of 199.00. I have flushed everything but FPC.

** *Flushing FPC is not an option in our workflow since we rely on varnish with our traffic level.*

I have banned the URL from varnish on all varnish nodes as usual with:

```
sudo varnishadm ban req.url '~' '<my product url>'
```

I have saved the product, I have checked the indexes, I have flushed the magento caches (minus FPC), I have flushed the URL for the specific URL in varnish and witnessed the uncached page load the same incorrect price over and over again.

---

### How can I flush the Product Display Page without flushing FPC?